# Add record to database if not already there

Tags: sqlite

I want to add a value to my table if it is not already there. I cant use UNIQUE as there will be multiple lines with the same value. I've tried below but `$result` returns `bool(true)`. How can I do that?

```
$ishashinDB = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE hash = :hash;');
$ishashinDB->bindValue(':hash', $Ihash);
$result = $ishashinDB->execute();
var_dump($result);

                if ($result == 0) {
                        $addhash = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (hash) VALUES (:hash)");
                        $addhash -> bindParam(':hash', $Ihash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $addhash -> execute();
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this below execute:

> $result = $ishashinDB->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: That causes an error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a
 non-object

Comment: Now must works. If you have any problem see the docs: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that too but $result is bool(false).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!